# if is possible to do if mobile hands-free is connected and i speak hands-free microphone and stream in mobile speaker?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I'm doing through the Bluetooth hands-free microphone and want to use the phone speaker for audio feedback at the same time.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

No it can't be possible. Because by default if takes any one as connection to stream. if you use hands free then it streams form it only or else from device for both mic and speaker. Kindly refer android manager for more details.